# Take value from ForeignKey and SUM it. Django

Tags: python, django

I have no idea how to say on the title. but check it here:

my `model.py`

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class EmpLoan(models.Model):
    status = models.BooleanField('Status', default=False)
    nominal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='emploan')

class EmpInstallment(models.Model):
    nominal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
    loan = models.ForeignKey(EmpLoan, related_name='empinstallment')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and my `views.py`

```
class EmpLoanListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'emploans'
    model = models.EmpLoan

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmpLoanListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = EmpLoanForm()
        return context
```

and here my `template_loan.html`

```
{% for emploan in emploans %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ emploan.employee.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ emploan.nominal|intcomma }},-</td>
  <td>{{ emploan.installment.nominal|intcomma }},-</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

here I am trying to access data from `EmpInstallment` model with `emploan.installment.nominal` but it doesn't work.

how to how to take data from ForeignKey and `sum` it in my case?...

it will return get() returned more than one ContentType -- it returned 2! since will have more than one value so I need to `sum` it also.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that code wouldn't give that error; you should always post the actual error and traceback you get.

To sum the installments for each loan, you can use aggregation. In this case you can override the `get_queryset` method of your model to add that aggregation call.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(EmpLoanListView, self).get_queryset()
    return qs.annotate(installment_sum=Sum('empinstallment__nominal'))
```

Now, each item in emploans has an extra field, `installment_sum`, which sums the related installment values.

Note you need to import Sum from django.db.models.

You probably also want to add `.select_related('employee')` to the end of that call, to reduce the number of calls needed to look up the employee names.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a `@property` method will work:
For each `EmpLoan` instance, you can access the total of `nominal` that it has from the **ReverseRelation** with `EmpInstallment`.

```
from django.db.models import Sum

class EmpLoan(models.Model):
    status = models.BooleanField('Status', default=False)
    nominal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='emploan')

    @property
    def total_nominal(self):
        if self.empinstallment.all():
            return self.empinstallment.aggregate(Sum('nominal')).get('nominal__sum')
        # if don't need None value, just: return 0
```

In your templates, you will access :

```
{% for emploan in emploans %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ emploan.employee.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ emploan.nominal|intcomma }},-</td>
    <td>{{ emploan.total_nominal|intcomma }},-</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```